# Passing a float between multiple viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, xcode, tabs, nsuserdefaults, multiviews

Im trying to send a float from one viewcontroller to another.

Ok Ive tried using NSUserDefaults to go about this. First I tested it with a string and it worked, but now I'm struggling to do the same with my float. Any help would be appreciated! :) Heres my code

In my firstviewcontroller.h file i have

```
IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
IBOutlet UILabel *greeting;
 float RWI; 
float Liters;

@property(nonatomic) float *Liters;`
@property(nonatomic, retain); IBOutlet UILabel *greeting;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;

-(IBAction) updatePrefs:(id) sender; @property(nonatomic) float *RWI; `
```

In my .m file I have
    float RWI;
    //@synthesize RWI;
    @synthesize Liters;
    @synthesize nameField,greeting;

```
-(IBAction) updatePrefs:(id) sender
{   
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:nameField.text forKey:@"greeting"];
[prefs setFloat:20 forKey:@"Liters"];
[prefs synchronize]
```

Then for the secondviewcontroller.h file

```
IBOutlet UILabel *greeting;
float *Liters;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *greeting;
@end`
```

In my .m file

```
@implementation secondviewcontroller
@synthesize greeting;
@synthesize Liters;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];NSString *prefs = 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"greeting"];
float Liters  = [prefs floatForKey:@"Liters"];
greeting.text = prefs;  
}`
```

Why does my float give errors?  Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3):

The error you are experienced is due to the fact that `prefs` is NOT `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` as it should be, because in your previous statement you do

```
NSString *prefs = 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"greeting"];
```

therefore, `prefs` is a `NSString` object. You need to modify

```
float Liters  = [prefs floatForKey:@"Liters"];
```

to

```
float Liters  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"Liters"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a float variable from one view to another view  by implementing getter and setters in the delegate class.

In delegate .h file

Include UIApplication delegate

```
@interface DevAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

float currentValue;

- (void) setCurrentValue:(float) currentValue;
- (float ) getCurrentValue;
```

In Delegate implementation class .m

```
-(void) setCurrentValue:(float) storydata{
currentValue = storydata;
}

-(float ) getCurrentValue{
return currentValue;
}
```

So the value you to assess is set in the currentValue  by setters method and class where you want the value ,just use the getter method.

All the best